# buttons resetting position after moved

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a condition in my app that determines whether a button is needed. If not, I want my other buttons to move up to fill the space. I am doing this through the following code: (for each button)

```
    var yMove:CGFloat = 40

    let y = button.frame.origin.y
    let x = button.frame.origin.x
    let h = button.frame.height
    let w = button.frame.width


    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y - yMove, w, h)
```

They show for a fraction of a second that they are initialized to the new position (good) but then they return to the old position (bad) . Why is this happening? Thank you, all help is appreciated!

Also, it might be worth noting that I am initializing the views from the ViewDidLoad method. And there are **NO** constraints set on the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the original position of your button and use the value when needed.

```
var ogButtonFrame: CGRect!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//before you do anything with your button save the frame here
   ogButtonFrame = button.frame
}

func returnButtonToOriginalPosition(){
   button.frame = ogButtonFrame
}
```

**BTW Autolayout and constraints are your friends!! Use them**